# How to run lex file?

Tags: lex

Here is my lex file

```
 %%
 .|\n    ECHO;
 %%
```

How to run this program in windows? How to compile this?

Please help me

Comment: You don't "run" a lex file.  You feed it to a program like [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/), which generates C or C++ code for you, and then you incorporate that in your project.

Comment: ok how do i do that... please help me

Comment: Step 0: [Download flex](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm) and install it (adding to %PATH% if necessary).  Step 1: `flex "the file's name"` (adding the `-+` option if you want C++ code rather than C).  Step 2: take lex.yy.c* and add it to your project.  It's pretty simple, really.

Answer (score 2):

Use this procedure to compile:

[How to compile LEX/YACC files on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows/5545924#5545924)

Basically:

```
flex olex.l
gcc lex.yy.c -o olex.exe
```

And this modified file:

```
%%

.|"\n"  { ECHO; }

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this works for you.