# flex and bison in windows doesn't work

Tags: windows, bison, flex-lexer

I read [How to compile LEX/YACC files on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows?answertab=oldest). I do all steps but in my CMD it doesnt find any flex or bison ..., can you help me ?

Comment: Without more info, its hard to say what you did wrong, but most likely you failed to do step 5.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Win flex-bison](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/). It is better and easier to be used.