# Compile and run flex programs on windows

Tags: c, compiler-construction, cmd

I write simple flex program and run it in linux with following code

```
flex filename.l
cc lex.yy.c -lfl
./a.out
```

but now I want to run it in windows I do orders in following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows) now I am trying to compile flex file with following commend but it says that cc is not recognized then I try to compile it with following commend

```
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

and it says that `cannot find -lfl`, then I try this

```
gcc lex.yy.c
```

but i got a lot of error for example `undefined reference to yywrap`. what should I do to recognize flex libraries ?

Comment: Find were your flex library is located. It'll probably be called libfl.so or libfl.a. Then add -L<path to your library> to the line where you compile lex.yy.c. Its basically complaining that it cant find the library.

Comment: @PaulRooney I find libfl.a its in "C:\GnuWin32\lib". then  tried this commands `gcc lex.yy.c -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib"` and `gcc lex.yy.c -L "C:\GnuWin32\lib"` and `gcc lex.yy.c -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib" -l"libfl.a"` and ... but no one works

Comment: @PaulRooney I used `gcc lex.yy.c -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib" -lfl` and now it's okay, thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that it cant find the library. On linux it would be under /usr/bin or usr/local/bin which are both on the system path. On windows there is no such standard place for libraries.

When you use the -lfl option it will search on the system path for a file called libfl.o (shared library) or libfl.a (static library) and link your binary with this file.

So what you need to do is provide the location of the library using the -L option for gcc.

Your new compile command would therefore be.

```
gcc lex.yy.c -L<path to library> -lfl
```