# How to compile lex-yacc-files on windows 10 using dev-cpp?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, dev-c++

I have followed all the steps described here: [How to compile LEX/YACC files on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows)

But I am getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages you received are only warnings from the **C** compiler (gcc) and are not fatal errors. The program will execute and function correctly if you invoke the binary by typing `hello` at the command prompt.

You can make the warnings go away by adding this to the top of the `Hello.y` file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}
```

(This seems like an omission in the answer you linked to....)

Comment: The problem is in hello.y, not hello.l, as is evident from the error message.

Comment: No worries. I added the other needed header :)