# I changed`bison -v -d ... `To `bison -d ...` In `makefile` in `codeblocks` but it make error

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, codeblocks

I changed`bison -v -d ...`To `bison -d ...` In `makefile` in `codeblocks`.but when compile nothing has been changed and shows error. 
use Code::Block 16.01 so I get this error:

```
   -------------- Build: Debug in testB (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

 bison -v -d C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Compressed\f90toC\f90toC\f90.y -o C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Compressed\f90toC\f90toC/f90.parser.cc
Execution of 'bison -v -d C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Compressed\f90toC\f90toC\f90.y -o C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Compressed\f90toC\f90toC/f90.parser.cc' in 'D:\testB\testB' failed.

 -------------- Run: Debug in testB (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

 Checking for existence: D:\testB\testB\bin\Debug\testB.exe
```

my `Makefile` is here:

```
CC = gcc  -ggdb
OBJ = f90main.o f90decl.o f90arg.o f90.tab.o lex.yy.o symb.o ptree.o \
      f90mod.o f90print.o

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $<

all: f90

lex.yy.c:  f90.lex
    flex -i f90.lex

f90.tab.c: f90.y f90.h
    bison -d f90.y

f90: $(OBJ) f90.h
    $(CC) -o ff90 $(OBJ)

why:
    bison -d -v f90.y
clean:
    -rm *.o lex.yy.c f90.tab.c f90.tab.h f90.output

F = f90toC
tar:
    tar -cvf f90toC-test.tar $(F)/f90.lex $(F)/f90.y $(F)/*.h $(F)/*.c $(F)/tests $(F)/doc $(F)/Makefile $(F)/README $(F)/File_index

bak:
    cp *.c backup
    cp *.h backup
    cp *.y backup
    cp *.lex backup
    cp Makefile backup
```

CodeBlocks  snapshot 1

[image]

also you can refer to [want to compile product Fortran to c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089768/want-to-compile-product-fortran-to-c)
So anybody could help me.

Can I build my project in visual studio 2015 as 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx
Is it compatible makefile project?

Regards

Comment: Are you sure the makefile is used for the build? It contains relative paths only, but the execution log you shows absolute paths.

Comment: I am sure,This is the routine behavior of codeblocks.Actually in codeblocks when you create a temp project and add files ,it sorted files in specified categories. Specially makefile you can open it.but I don't know why it doesn't change makefile when I edit that, and also problem in compilation appears.

Comment: That does not seem to be related to C, so don't spam tags. `.cc` is not typical for C code either, but C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved as I follow instruction in

[How to compile LEX/YACC files on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows)

and use this project

http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/People/mdewing/f90toC/

and make the project in command prompt.Not
 Visual Studio 2015 environment so I use ff90.exe to compile fortran .f90 files to .c files as the instruction mentioned .but the ff90.exe is not really strong and take errors in such tests.this is related to the developer