# build error : undefined reference to `yyFlexLexer::yyFlexLexer(std::istream*, std::ostream*)

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I have used Flex in my application on windows machine and the compiler is `mingw32-make`. I got an an build error on My C++ code.

I have done Flex installation and I have done routed include and lib directory on `PATH`.
The code line is:

```
const char * filename;

std::fstream file;

file.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);

yyFlexLexer * scanner;

scanner = new yyFlexLexer(&file);
```

The error is:

```
"File.cpp:63: undefined reference to `yyFlexLexer::yyFlexLexer(std::istream*, std::ostream*)'"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not provided enough information to identify what your problem is. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. That should include everything necessary to compile your project: all source files (if there is more than one) and the build procedure. In order to decrease the size of the post, please remove irrelevant details: in this case, you could probably remove all the lexical patterns and actions, leaving only the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File.cpp:63: undefined reference to `yyFlexLexer::yyFlexLexer(std::istream*, std::ostream*)
```

This means that your c++ lexer is either undefined, or defined under a different name.

You can't write the following, without compiling and linking the flex file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <FlexLexer.h>
int main()
{
  const char * filename= "file.txt";;
  std::fstream file;
  file.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);

  // better use auto scanner = std::make_unique<yyFlexLexer>(&file)
  yyFlexLexer * scanner; 
  // leaks memory
  scanner = new yyFlexLexer(&file);
}
```

The above won't work without writing a flex file, running flex (which by default generates `lex.yy.cc`), and then compiling and linking the generated code. You can read all about it in [Generating C++ Scanners](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx).

If you did compile and link the generated code, you still may get this error if a named scanner was created. Basically, if your program has more than one scanner, giving different names to different scanners is the correct solution. In that case you need to access the correct name.

This is all in the flex manual, at the [Generating C++ Scanners](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx) section. Which I quote here:

> If you want to create multiple (different) lexer classes, you use
>   the `-P' flag (or the `prefix=' option) to rename each yyFlexLexer to
>   some other xxFlexLexer. You then can include `<FlexLexer.h>' in your
>   other sources once per lexer class, first renaming yyFlexLexer as
>   follows:

```
#undef yyFlexLexer 
#define yyFlexLexer xxFlexLexer 
#include <FlexLexer.h> 

#undef yyFlexLexer   
#define yyFlexLexer zzFlexLexer   
#include <FlexLexer.h>
```

> if, for example, you used `%option prefix="xx"' for one of your
>   scanners and `%option prefix="zz"' for the other.

This is ugly and tricky, but it is the way flex works with C++. This has been documented as experimental since the 90's, or before. I assume that it won't change.

Comment: You need to watch out for angle brackets and Markdown characters when you're cutting and pasting random text into an answer. Alternatively, you can use Ctl-K to turn the quote into a code block, which is a bit uglier but less work. I also changed the manual link to the official manual

Comment: Thanks @MichaelVeksler.
I have generated lex.asc.cc by using command 'Flex++ Lexer.l' in command line. I have added Flex  **includepath & LIBS** on the _.pro_ file and then I tried to build my application in Qt Creator. I have added some more line to use flex on my application with reference
[link](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3557-Flex-Bison-and-qmake). But I'm getting error 'lex.asc.cc:242:23: fatal error: FlexLexer.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.' So Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @VenkatesanSoundiraRajan you must find where `FlexLexer.h` is located on your system. The installation of `flex` should have installed this file. If it is not installed, then reinstall flex. If it is installed, then make sure your include path includes the folder that contains it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelVeksler I have installed Flexlexer.h with **Flex 2.5.4** and rooted in 'PATH'. The location Flex is _D:\Public\Myinstall\GnuWin32\include_

Comment: @VenkatesanSoundiraRajan in that case, you didn't set up your include path correctly. This warrants a completely different question about setting up include paths in your compiler. Please Google for a setp-by-step  explanation of how to set up include path in your compiler. Hint: it is different between Visual Studio and gcc. It is different between IDE and command line, between cmd.exe and bash, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelVeksler you may right but I have [cross verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows) with their example. I got an warning 
` D:\LocalData\Downloads\hellex-master\hellex-master>gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o hello.exe

hello.l: In function 'main':

hello.l:19:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'yyparse' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      yyparse();`


and hello.exe is not execute in my command window.

Comment: @VenkatesanSoundiraRajan yyparse() and y.tab.c are completely different beasts. They are in the  output of your bison or yacc. Also, you did not set up your include path on that command line. You must provide it with `-I "D:\Public\Myinstall\GnuWin32\include"` if you are running on cmd.exe, or possibly `-I 'D:\Public\Myinstall\GnuWin32\include'` if in bash. Other than that, you should check why you are getting that warning

Comment: @VenkatesanSoundiraRajan anyway, searching for "*gcc include path*" will give you helpful documentation at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: Solved by proper environment variable PATH setting & fresh reinstalling all softwares pakcage, which is mentioned above.  Thanks @MichaelVeksler